# iOS Charts - Equidistant Y Values?

Tags: ios, ios-charts

For the iOS Charts library, does anybody know how to make the y axis values equidistant from one another? So in the following picture the "1" line would be halfway up the graph?

[image]

Comment: Which graph api you are using ?

Comment: barChartView in iOS Charts in Swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `axisMinimum` to zero will result in your desired output.

```
//chartView is the object of BarChartView class.
let yAxisLeft : YAxis = self.chartView.leftAxis
yAxisLeft.axisMinimum = 0
```

[image]

It will remain consistent for other values too.

[image]